# What does 馬鹿も一芸 mean in English?

Tags: translation, expressions, idioms

I'm wondering how 馬鹿も一芸 should be translated into English. [EDICT-based dictionary sites](http://beta.jisho.org/search/%E9%A6%AC%E9%B9%BF%E3%82%82%E4%B8%80%E8%8A%B8) list this phrase with the following translation:

> 馬鹿も一芸
>   even a fool has a talent

Is this translation correct?

Comment: Where did you see this phrase?

Comment: Dictionary says: even a fool has one talent. Guess it's right?

Comment: @Aki The question is "can we trust the dictionary?". See the discussion on my answer below, especially snailboat's comment.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that "even a fool has a talent" is a fitting translation. (If one would want to say that it should be something like 馬鹿にも一芸.)

Rather, 馬鹿も一芸 means something like "even being a fool can be a talent".

Comment: Honestly, I didn't know this idiom. And for some reason, Google lists many "translation/English dictionary" sites for this word. And higher-ranked pages which are unrelated to "translation/dictionary" were [this](http://the-kotowaza.seesaa.net/article/188350128.html) and [this](http://pets.yahoo.co.jp/qa/14108373689?p=1), one of which basically agrees with the Earthliŋ's suggestion. Maybe this is a "Japanese" proverb which is more popular outside of Japan?

Comment: @naruto How about 「阿呆にも一芸」?

Comment: @3to5 I didn't know that, either. Anyway "even a fool has a talent" and "even being a fool is a talent" both seem reasonable :) The first page Bing returned, which were not related to foreign language in any way, was using it as "being a fool is a talent" (I won't link it).

Comment: Quite a few dictionaries that I have access to lists this byword. Old [WWWJDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1C) gives the translation "even a fool has one talent", which is what I get from other sources as well.

Comment: @OskarLindberg When you say "a few dictionaries", do you mean online English-Japanese dictionaries or paper dictionaries? Many online dictionaries use the WWWJDIC database. It wouldn't be the first time that I saw a WWWJDIC entry for an expression/idiom with a questionable translation.

Comment: Not a paper dictionary, but this proverb website [ http://kotowazagyakubiki.seesaa.net/article/354329642.html ] seems to confirm Earthliŋ's statement. The site specifically says that this proverb does not mean "Even a fool will have a strong point".

Comment: So to sum it all up the words I posted isn't the correct translation? I found the idiom just by searching "Japanese idioms" :)

Comment: It looks like this was added to EDICT in the mid-90s based on a collection of proverbs put together in 1994 by Tim Duncan.  When someone responded to this particular idiom with "mmm, I've never heard of it... What is the resource?" [Duncan replied](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.lang.japan/pbZRECKyQFk/k6tLFyIM4I0J) that it was from David Galef's 1987 book *"'Even Monkeys Fall from Trees' and other Japanese Proverbs"*.  It does appear to be listed in this book, though it says only "Even a fool has one talent" and doesn't happen to list a source.